# php (7.4?) preloading - instantiate variables

Tags: php

i have numerous files, which dont particularly take long to load, but take about 2-4 secs to run per request, is there anyway to pre-run these functions.

i was trying to use php7.4 preloading, but it only seems to load class definitions and functions without being able to build objects in memory for use in subsequent requests

i was thinking about some kind of daemon, which i can run once and then communicate with it during the requests, restarting the daemon whenever the code changes

does php genuinely have to load and run everything per request?

Comment: Can you cache the data from the objects/methods?  So run them once and then hold onto the values in something like APCu?

Comment: What takes so long? Processing data - use cache. Loading resources - use resources scan cache to faster system lookup

Comment: If it's data which only needs to be computed once, there are many ways to do that… compute it on the first request that needs it, then cache it (e.g. in a file, memcached, Redis, whatever). Or have a cron job do that in regular intervals. In some way or another, you probably need some external data storage.

Comment: currently i use a rather obscure form of runtime code generation, it uses dynamic properties of stdclass to hold references to functions, it takes forever to plough through defining them

Comment: @mattrichards So do you really need to generate it every time? You can make dynamic files that are generated e.g. on deployment or on schedule

Comment: i have reduced it as much as possible, and only load what is needed for each request but it still takes a long time to get it up and running - i cant use apcu because the object properties are functions

Comment: Using runtime code generation is rarely going to perform well, can you save the code as a php file and then include that?

Comment: the code is stored in a data structure, which boils down to plain text function declarations, i extract the plaintext, assign a unique filename and require it allowing opcache to work, run the function and get back a stdclass object whose properties are mostly functions themselves, i suspect the slowness comes from using stdclass in the end, i'll try to use pointers to assoc arrays in the future, the original data structure is the key element because i should be able to change languages fairly easily if needed